# Is it possible to upgrade a production extension with local version?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that is installed from the Chrome Store that has an ID: XXX.
I have developed a new version for the extension and I want to make sure that the upgrade process happens properly (it needs to take the data from the old one and copy it to the new one due to changed data structure).

I'm using id XXX for the new local extension but when I load it, chrome overrides it and applies a new ID.

Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What is 'data' and how do you store it? There are quite a few storage mechanisms available.

Comment: @minj it's irrelevant. I have one data structure in the existing extension, the new one handles the data in a different way but it needs the old data for that. On the logic side everything is OK, i just want to make sure that it works before i push it to production. 
All I want to do is to simulate an upload to chrome store (which will override the current extension) but before i do that, i want to know everything works fine.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. Javascript has no persistence. Your options are localStorage, indexedDB, WebSQL, and chrome.storage.